# Rectangle Is Inside Polygon?

Tags: java, awt

How would I find out if any points of a given `Rectangle` are inside a `Polygon`?

I have tried:

```
final Point p = new Point(rect.x, rect.y);
return polygon.contains(p);
```

This half works. It only returns true when the top left corner of the rectangle is in the polygon (Yes, I do know why).

Is there a way to check if ANY of the points of the rectangle are in the polygon?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried [polygon.intersects(rect)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Polygon.html#intersects(java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D))?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the best way to do this:

`return polygon.intersects(rect);`

Comment: Contains first use intersects, then uses Crossing (looking at the implementation), there might be cases that contains will be better, worth a deeper check.

Answer (score 3):

[public boolean contains(Rectangle2D r)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Polygon.html#contains%28java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D%29)

So basically you need to do:

```
polygon.contains(rect)
```

Comment: This works better, but does ot check ALL the points. It merely just checks for a side of the rectangle ...

Comment: @JavaCoder-1337 documentation says `true if the interior of the Shape entirely contains the Rectangle2D`